# How can show 0 in a repeated statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show all policy business units but is only showing when exist values

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|  |client|  |policy_business_unit_id|  |cia_ensure_id|   |state|       
   1      MATT                  1                   1             0
   2      STEVE                 1                   1             0
   3      BILL                  1                   2             0
   4      LARRY                 1                   2             1
   5      MATT                  1                   2             1
   6      STEVE                 2                   2             2
   7      BILL                  2                   2             2
   8      LARRY                 2                   2             1
   9      MATT                  2                   1             1

|policy_business_units|
   |id|   |name|  |comercial_area_id|
     1     LIFE         1 
     2     ROB          1 
     3     CAR          1 
     4     RARE         1 
     5     RARE2        1 

|comercial_areas|
   |id|   |name|
    1      MICROSOFT
    2      APPLE

|cia_ensures|
   |id|   |name|
    1      ORANGE
    2      BT
    3      ATT
    4      MOVISTAR
    5      SPRINT
```

I'm getting this result it's ok but is not showing all policy_business units

```
 UNIT  V1  A1  N1   V2 A2  N2   V3  A3  N3   V4  A4  N4   V5  A5  N5
 LIFE  2   0   0    1   2  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
 ROB   0   1   0    0   1  2    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
```

Here is the query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6909d8/1

```
set @@local.group_concat_max_len=10000;
select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',
group_concat(concat(
'SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,', 
 SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,', 
 SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),
' 
FROM cia_ensures ce 
LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
AND ca.id=1  
Group by p.policy_business_unit_id;')
from cia_ensures
where id in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

I'm trying to show this:

```
 UNIT  V1  A1  N1   V2 A2  N2   V3  A3  N3   V4  A4  N4   V5  A5  N5
 LIFE  2   0   0    1   2  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
 ROB   0   1   0    0   1  2    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0 
 RARE  0   0   0    0   0  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0 
 RARE2 0   0   0    0   0  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
```

Please somebody can help me?

I will appreciate all help.

Comment: "INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id" is only going to return the ones that are in both of those tables.  Probably need to do some kind of a LEFT join instead?

Comment: Change the first `INNER JOIN policy_business_units` to `RIGHT JOIN policy_business_units`.

Comment: Other then what @TomasPastircak already said you also need to change the group by to `pb.name`

Comment: As for my previous comment [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56b78/4)

Comment: Thank you worked for me =) but no points for the answer? is ok?

Comment: I have a last question.. Tomas and Serpiton gave me the answer but the question is still active somebody needs to post an answer or is ok? I mean rabout the vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below changes if it helps you, I did not execute it just do some changes in query, so need to check at your end:

```
set @@local.group_concat_max_len=10000;
select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',
group_concat(concat(
'SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,', 
 SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,', 
 SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),
' 
FROM 
policy_business_units pb 
LEFT JOIN policies p 
ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
LEFT JOIN cia_ensures ce 
on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id 
LEFT JOIN comercial_areas ca 
ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
AND ca.id=1  
Group by pb.name;')
from cia_ensures
where id in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```